# ffprobe/ffmpeg exec doesn't return result on local machine, but works on production system

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I want to get the duration of a movie, using ffprobe (part of ffmpeg). 
The command line I'm using is this:

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of
default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1
path/to/video.mov
```

It works perfectly in the shell, gives me a result of 4.5554 (seconds).

However, if I call this command via exec on my local machine, I get an empty result.

```
var_dump( exec("ffprobe -v .......") );
returns string(0) ""
```

Now comes the burner: It works perfectly on the production machine, though!!

These are my configurations:

```
Local machine:        Mac OS 10.9.5,      PHP 5.6.11   ffmpeg 2.7.1
Production machine:   Mac OS Server 10.6  PHP 5.3.1    ffmpeg 2.7.2
```

Is this kind of a bug in PHP 5.6 or something???
Thanks, Matt

Comment: so capture the return value and examine that. `exec($cmd, $output, $return_val); var_dump($return_val)`

Comment: `var_dump($return_val)` returns `int(5)` which is wrong, the movie is 4 seconds

Comment: `var_dump($output)` returns `array(0) { }`

Comment: the return value has NOTHING to do with your movie length. it's how ffmpeg signals problems.

Comment: where can I look up what "problem code 5" will mean?

Comment: if I add 2>&1 et the end, if gives me: `string(67) " in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO" array(4) { [0]=> string(51) "dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart" [1]=> string(82) " Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO" [2]=> string(63) " Expected in: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/libJPEG.dylib" [3]=> string(67) " in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO" } int(133)`

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.

I had a 5 corrupt libraries in `Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib`. I had to copy and paste them from `/System/Library/Frameworks`to the XAMPP library folder and replace the old, corrupt ones by the fresh ones.

Now, all works fine, locally and on the production machine.

Thanks!!!